# Utilizing Java, I need to modify the AgeGuess program I made before to do the following as written below in Lab 2 Exercise 1

Tags: java, random

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AgeGuess {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in); // reading from keyboard new scanner object
        
System.out.print ("Enter the name: ");
String name = scan.nextLine(); // Adding name

System.out.print ("Enter the age: ");
int ageGuess = scan.nextInt(); // Adding Age

System.out.println ("Name is "+ name); // Display name

System.out.println ("Age is "+ ageGuess); //Display age Guess

//***********************************************************************************************
// Lab 2 Exercise 1: Modify the AgeGuess program to do the following:
// Declare a new int variable - initialize age to a random integer between 0 and 100 (inclusive)
// Asks the user for a guess, save the guess in the ageGuess variable
// Display the correct answer
```

Comment: What part are you having trouble with? Please see: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I hope you mean something like this

  ```
       Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.print ("Enter the name: "); 
       String name = scan.nextLine(); // Adding name
       System.out.println("Generating age for user "+ name);
       int generatedAge = new Random().nextInt(100);
       System.out.print ("Guess the user age: "); 
       int ageGuess =  scan.nextInt(); // Adding Age

       System.out.println ("Name is "+ name); // Display name
       System.out.println ("Age is "+ ageGuess); //Display age Guess

       System.out.println("Generated age of user is: "+ generatedAge);
       System.out.println("Guessed user age is : "+ ageGuess);

       if(generatedAge == ageGuess){
           System.out.println("Congratulations !!! The guessed age of the user is correct ");
       }
  ```

Comment: please dont do the kids homework...

Comment: Thank you! What was very confusing for me, was what I should have to start with to change on my original input I made. I see you changed the original area of "Enter the Age" into "Guess the user age", while utilizing the new system.out.println in conjunction with the the int generatedAge line there. I wasn't sure If I should put that at the end either. My last question is if I have to inport the Random or not? Being new to this and having tons of questions is difficult especially with everything online now. Thank you so much!

Comment: Seems like its your lab work ;) and you need to research it further yourself. Btw you need to import the Random class which is in java.util package. Every utility methods or classes need to be imported for use, but you don't see System or other classes imported because they are already available. ( which is "lang" package, it is auto-imported by every java program we write) aside from classes and methods available in lang we need to import every thing we use. Hope this helps, and sorry for my english if it doesn't make sense. I am happy that you analyzed it. Keep up the good work and research